# NDSolveValue`MethodOfLines, the Method : "SpatialDiscretization" "TensorProductGrid""MinPoints" Option does not work in 2-d

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm applying NDSolveValue to 2-D diffusion equation with "Method of Lines":

```
eqns = {D[T[t, x, y], t] == D[T[t, x, y], x, x] + D[T[t, x, y], y, y]};  
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];  
init = {T[0, x, y] == If[0.4 < x < 0.6 && 0.4 < y < 0.6, 1, 0]};  
bcs = DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == 0,x == 1 || x == 0| y == 0 || y == 1];   

sol1 = NDSolveValue[{eqns, init, bcs},T, {t, 0, 0.1}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], MaxStepSize -> 0.0001]
```

the above code works.

But when I tried to control the spatial discretization grid points:

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{eqns, init, bcs}, 
  T, {t, 0, 0.01}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega],
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 125}}, MaxStepSize -> 0.0001
  ]
```

it failed with an error message (`NDSolveValue::moptx`):
[image: error]

Unable to identify the problem, I searched the documentation and found an example:

```
s2 = NDSolve[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[t, x]\)\) == 1/1000 \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(u[t, x]\)\) - u[t, x] \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(u[t, x]\)\), 
   u[0, x] == Sin[2 \[Pi] x], u[t, 0] == u[t, 1]}, 
  u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> 128}}}]
```

which works, except that its in 1-D.

So what's wrong with my code?

Comment: To be more specific, since you've: 1. defined the domain with `∈`, 2. used `DirichletCondition`, `NDSolve` automatically turns to `FiniteElement` method, while `MinPoints` is a sub-option of  `TensorProductGrid` method, so the warning pops up.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I have manually specified "MethodOfLines", so why is "FiniteElement" still triggered without warning.

Comment: Notice `FiniteElement` and `TensorProductGrid` are both sub-method of 
 `MethodOfLines` in this case. As already mentioned, `NDSolve` automatically uses `FiniteElement` when `∈` or `DirichletCondition` is used, at least now. (Well, perhaps a better warning should be given in this case e.g. `TensorProductGrid` cannot handle `DirichletCondition`, sub-method has been changed to `FiniteElement`? )